# Django: How to use modelform on dynamic attributes..?

Tags: django, django-models

It's kind of tricky question, It's hard for me to expain what I want so please comment this post what should be edited. Thnx.

So there's a situation where there will be tons of dynamic form inputs. What do I mean by word "dynamic" is that - every attribute (form input) will be stored in table not as column but as value and name of form can be easily edited in the feature with out using migrations. Here's a scheme:

[image: attribute relationship]

I want to have automatic modelform generated from this scheme. Django could just pick all field names/values/types from table1_attr table. And handle them as it's done with one-column-per-field scheme.

I know that it's possible to add any field later into the model, and then to use "south", but I really afraid of data migration with south. Because I had a lot of segfaults and errors before with this tool. Ofcourse this is an option, and if this scheme will fail - then I'll use usual solution. Btw middleware solutions also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is statically defined form in python code and NoSQL storage. As for Redis you can store data in hashes with numbers of keys.